# typedef of two different function pointers is valid?

Tags: c

Can some one explain what exactly the code means and is it valid to do typedef like that and using "name" in function call arguments ?

```
typedef uint8 (*Funcptr) (name);
typedef uint8 (*Funcptr1) (name);

typedef struct {
    Funcptr func;
    Funcptr1 func_1;
} a;
```

Comment: Is `name` defined prior to this (e.g. as a typedef) ?

Comment: Yes it is typedef as const void*

Answer (score 0):

There are pointer to function returning an *uint8* and getting a *name* in argument (probably an other typedef, or is invalid if undefined)

Example :

```
typedef char * name; /* added to be able to compile */

typedef uint8 (*Funcptr) (name);

uint8 foo(name s)
{
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  Funcptr f = &foo;
  char bar[] = "bar";

  (*f)(bar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid, provided `uint8` and `name` are types that have been defined previously.

The declaration `typedef uint8 (*Funcptr) (name);` says `Funcptr` is a type for a pointer to a function that takes a `name` as an argument and returns a `uint8`.

In general, a C declaration such as `uint8 (*Funcptr) (name)` gives a type (in this case `uint8`) and a sample expression (in this case `(*Funcptr) (name)`) and means “When I use `Funcptr` this way, the expression has type `uint8`. So we have:

- `(*Funcptr) (name)` is a `uint8`.
- Therefore, `(*Funcptr)` must be a function taking a `name` and returning a `uint8`.
- Therefore, `Funcptr` must be a pointer to a function taking a `name` and returning a `uint8`.

Then, since it is a `typedef`, we know that `Funcptr` is the name of this type, rather than being an object that is a pointer to a function taking a `name` and returning a `uint8`.

Comment: thanks Eric Postpischil i understand, appreciate your answer